# osb muliple endpoint on business

Tags: esb, osb

in Weblogic  12.1.2.0.0 and OSB : 11.1.1.7 
We need to implement a message flow that contains a "for each" to invoke a business service many times changing its endpoint. 
The differents endpoints are in a xquery file.
But we have a problem, because these endpoints are for a development environment and we need to deploy it in a production environment.
The endpoints in the xquery file don´t appear in the cutomizarion file
How can I change the endpoints acording the correct environment? any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it from the top.

- Avoid callouts in For-Each loops where possible. Look to use split-joins, or, preferably, a pre-packaged split-join framework like [GenericParallel](http://genericparallel.com).
- I assume you have already worked out how to change the biz ref endpoint dynamically, using the `routing options` node. I don't like how it breaks monitoring and tracing, since you're using one biz ref to point to X real endpoints, but that's your decision. I would prefer a routing table to X biz refs instead, but I understand that's not always possible due to design constraints.
- Per-environment customisation in OSB is less than ideal. My preferred approach is to export the sbconfig.jar, then customise it for each environment using a library like [OSB-Config-WLST-Configurator](https://github.com/tomecode/OSB-Config-WLST-Configurator). That way, the configjar is environment-agnostic, but you have the capability to change any setting when you deploy to a particular environment (e.g. change OWSM policies to disallow UsernameToken in production, or enforce HTTPS only in environments that support it, or change service account details etc). Configurator works on xquery files as well, so you can search and replace what you need to.

Comment: We need multiple endpoints on one biz, because the design must be like this, because there are a lot of endpoints.
If I want to use OSB-Config-WLST-Configurator I need to change my current deploy method. 
I will look at how to use spli-joins or GenericParallel.
Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just create one JAR per environment with your XQuery only. (Resource JAR) Then you deploy your interface JAR and then your endpoing XQuery JAR in same deployment session, replacing wrong or old data.

Every time you deploy your interface JAR, you need to import also your XQuery JAR, but just need to create your XQuery JAR one time.

In order to create your XQuery JAR you can go to your development environment, create session, edit your XQuery, export without closing (or discarding) session and then you can discard the changes.